# Does a system tray have events that I can catch?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a transparent SystemTray

```
SystemTray.SetOpacity(this, 0.0);
```

on page that have a small title.

When I open a SystemTray items by holding a clock's zone, the items of SystemTray overlap the page title.
I need to catch events of showing/hiding the SystemTray and move my title lower/upper.

The question: Does a system tray have events that I can catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.. as per msdn it does not have any events for SystemTray http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.systemtray(v=vs.92).aspx